# In ASP.net MVC razor, i have to give a alert message based on the dropdown selected value. the following is the code

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

if the user selects "Fresher" from the dropdown, and if he doesn't enter any value in Company detail. it should give a alert message.

what is the javascript condtion to get the alert message ?

any help is appriciable.
Thanks

The razor code is :

```
<div class="form-group">

  <label>Current Status</label><span class="text text-danger">*</span> @Html.DropDownList("employmentStatus", new SelectList(new Dictionary
  <int, string> { { 0, "Current Status" }, { 1, "Fresher" }, { 2, "Employed" }, { 3, "Un-Employed" } }, "Key", "Value"), new { @class = "form-control", @id = "employmentStatus" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employmentStatus, "", new { @class = "text-danger"
    })
</div>

<div class="form-group">

  <label>Company Detail</label><span class="text text-danger">*</span> @Html.EditorFor(model => model.currentCompany, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@id= "currentCompany" } }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.currentCompany,
  "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

The javascript code is :

```js
if ($("#employmentStatus").val() == "Fresher" || ("#employmentStatus").val() == "Employed" && ("#currentCompany").val() == "" || ("#currentCompany").val() == null) {
  alert('Please select Current Company Name')
  return false;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Whit is the error that you see? Unless you ask specific question you will not get the right answer.

Comment: Missing `$` sign for `("#employmentStatus").val()`, `("#currentCompany").val()` and `("#currentCompany").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumption:**

You have a button or form event that firing `onSubmit` method before posting data to API.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form" }))
{
  // Form inputs
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return onSubmit()" class="btn btn-primary">
}
```

Since you specify the `<option>` value as `Dictionary` key, while label text as `Dictionary` value.

```
@Html.DropDownList("employmentStatus",
         new SelectList(new Dictionary<int, string>
         {
                { 0, "Current Status" },
                { 1, "Fresher" },
                { 2, "Employed" },
                { 3, "Un-Employed" }
         }, "Key", "Value"),
         new { @class = "form-control", @id = "employmentStatus" })
```

> Rendered HTML

```html
<select class="form-control" id="employmentStatus" name="employmentStatus">
  <option value="0">Current Status</option>
  <option value="1">Fresher</option>
  <option value="2">Employed</option>
  <option value="3">Un-Employed</option>
</select>
```

Hence, you need to check the selected option's value with `Dictionary` key and `currentCompany` input element cannot be empty string or `null`.

```js
if ($("#employmentStatus").val() == "1" 
  && ($("#currentCompany").val() == "" || $("#currentCompany").val() == null)) {
  alert('Please select Current Company Name');
  return false;
}
```

OR

```js
if ($("#employmentStatus option:selected")[0].text == "Fresher"
  && ($("#currentCompany").val() == "" || $("#currentCompany").val() == null)) {
  alert('Please select Current Company Name');
  return false;
}
```